# Set a property of an object in a Expect.Call

Tags: rhino-mocks

It's kind of hard to explain what I'm searching for but my example should clarify it.

I have next code:

```
var schedule = ScheduleUtil.CreateScheduleDto(user, user);
Expect.Call(() => _scheduleRepository.Save(schedule));
```

Now, what I want to do is when this Save call is made, the schedule.id property should be set to another value (1 for instance).

I do not want to mock schedule. Can this be done? The Save method doesn't return a value, so that's not a possiblity, but I do want the object schedule to be modified.

UPDATE: Maybe a small example will clarify what I exactly want.

Say there's a class with a method Save:

public void Create(Entity entity)
{
    //entity is saved to database
    //entity.id is updated with the created id in database
}

So, before the create, entity.id is -1, after the create it is > 0.

Now, there's a service that uses this Create. Code contracts on this service method say that before it is called, the entity must have an id equal to -1, after it is called it must have an id > 0 (preconditions and postconditions).

So, what I need is something like this:
var entity = new Entity(); //id == -1
Expect.Call(() => _instance.Create(entity);
//Now the entity.id should be a random number > 0. This is what I need, to have Rhino Mocks update the id of entity to a given integer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  If you're not mocking the `_scheduleRepository`, Rhino Mocks doesn't know about it.  Why don't you want to mock the `_scheduleRepository`?

**EDIT:** Ok, now I see what you want to do.  Use the "WhenCalled" extension method to define code to be executed when Rhino.Mocks intercepts the call.  Something like this should work:

```
_scheduleRepository.Expect(s => s.Save(schedule)).WhenCalled(a => ((Schedule) a.Arguments[0]).Id = 1);
```

Comment: I am mocking the _scheduleRepository. But when I call the Save(schedule), I also want Rhino Mocks to change the id of the schedule.

Comment: I added a small example to clarify what I need.

Comment: @Lieven If you can mock the "_instance" variable and the "Create" method is virtual, you can use the expectation I show above to set the entity's Id to anything you want.  It's not clear to me why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah, I'm terribly sorry, I hadn't seen your EDIT. Thx. Off course this is exactly what I was looking for.