# RhinoMocks: How to run custom delegate with parameter supplied to method?

Tags: .net, vb.net, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have a class that has a create method, passing into it a POCO entity.  What I want to happen is that I attach a delegate to the method call like so:

```
stubObject.Stub(Function(i) i.Create(Arg(of MyObject).Is().Anything))) _
   .Return(True)
```

What I want to do is to take the instance of the parameter passed to Create and run a custom action.  I thought Do() with a delegate would do the trick, but I can't get RhinoMocks 3.6 (.NET 4) to allow me to enter a parameters.

Where am I doing wrong?  I can't do this:

```
stubObject.Stub(Function(i) i.Create(Arg(of MyObject).Is().Anything))) _
   .Return(True) _
   .Do(Sub(i) ...)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the signature of the method you're trying to mock?

Comment: `Function Create(obj as MyObject) As Boolean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the "WhenCalled" option.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387299/set-a-property-of-an-object-in-a-expect-call) for an example of how it can be used to grab the arguments passed to the mocked call.